# Is it possible run files in JAR file using Java?

Tags: java, io

I want add a file into the jar package but this is a separate file from the java program, can I run it and if I can run it, how can I run it? Can you recomment anything?

Thanks.

Comment: Like .txt file?

Comment: Can be any soy type, images or executable files

Comment: You want to look into embedded resources.  Take a look at [`Class#getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) and [`Class#getResource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible; java doesn't run arbitrary executables; your OS does. Java ask your OS to run an executable, but OSes generally do not have the ability to run executables from within zip files. Let alone jmod files.

If your java application can read and process the data itself (example: Render a swing JLabel object with some PNG as its image), then you can to this:

```
YourClass.class.getResource("open_url.png")
```

Will get you an inputstream for the stated file, as long as that file is in the same place that `YourClass.class` is - even if it is in a jar file or jmod file.

However, if you have an .exe, you'd have to extract the executable, save it to a tmp dir, and then ask the OS to run that file. Saving executables to temp dirs is a little tricky (if it's a global temp dir, some other user could overwrite your executable in the middle, and thus run its code in your process, you see how that's security-wise quite a big issue). But, you can do it. Note that this makes your app not platform independent anymore, of course.